# How to display transactional emails in main menu in admin panel in magento?

Tags: xml, magento

I have a simple problem here. I want to display transactional email tab as a new menu tab in main header menu.
By default it displays as 
System > Transactional Emails

I want to include it in main menu right next to System tab.

I have changed in local/Mage/Adminhtml/etc/adminhtml.xml

```
<config>
    <menu>
    <system translate="title" module="adminhtml">
            <title>Manage Emails</title>
            <sort_order>80</sort_order>
<!--             <action>adminhtml/system</action> -->
            <children>
            <email_template translate="title">
                    <title>Transactional Emails</title>
                    <action>adminhtml/system_email_template</action>
                    <sort_order>60</sort_order>
                </email_template>
            <config translate="title">
                    <title>Configuration</title>
                    <action>adminhtml/system_config</action>
                    <sort_order>110</sort_order>
                </config>
            </children>

     </system>
     </menu>
</config>
```

As You can see I must have to put config tab with Transactional Emails tab to make them work.
If I remove config tab from it then the whole transational emails module doesn't work.
I cant load any template in admin panel.

I dont want the config tab with Transactional Emails Tab. 
Please Help me to solve this issue. I am using Magento 1.5.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same file you mentioned add

```
<email_template translate="title">
    <title>Transactional Emails</title>
    <action>adminhtml/system_email_template</action>
    <sort_order>100</sort_order>
</email_template>
```

after `</system>` tag
here in middle (may be about line:115)

```
</children>
        </system>   <!--after this add-->


        <email_template translate="title">  <--
            <title>Transactional Emails</title>  <--
            <action>adminhtml/system_email_template</action>  <--
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>  <--
        </email_template>  <--


    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
```

**P.S :** Don't forget to delete/comment

```
<email_template translate="title">
        <title>Transactional Emails</title>
        <action>adminhtml/system_email_template</action>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
</email_template>
```

`(line : 75 -79)`
Otherwise both transactional email would be seen

Hope this help you

Comment: hi Nikhil_K_R, Thanks for your reply. I have tried the solution. It displays Transactional Emails in main menu but when I try to add a new template and select default template from dropdown and click on load Template then nothing happens.
That is my real problem. Can you please help with this issue?

Comment: hi nikhil, I too have tried your solution in a new copy of magento and it works.
But i don't know, somehow its not working in my current project.
Can there be some other problem?

Comment: just copy the exact same xml file in your not-working-magento-copy.give a try

Comment: Glad to help you.If this solved your problem don't forget to vote up and add a tick(to  approve) to the answer.